# How to move div text box down

Tags: html, css

When the screen in "pic1" is wide the gray text box is on the right and logo is on the left.

I want to move the text only down in the center of the box.

But by moving the text i don't want the gray background to get bigger on the portrait / mobile view of the page, like on the screen shot "pic2"

CSS

```
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.logo {
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 91, 91);
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/main.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="logo">This is Logo</div>

    <div class="title">
      <h1>This is H1 Text Box with Gray Background</h1>
      <h3>This is H3 Text Box with Gray Background</h3>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

pic1
[image: pic1]

pic2
[image: pic2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the combination of:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
flex-direction: column;
```

All on `.title`.

This will vertically center your text, and can be seen in the following:

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.logo {
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 91, 91);
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/main.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="logo">This is Logo</div>

    <div class="title">
      <h1>This is H1 Text Box with Gray Background</h1>
      <h3>This is H3 Text Box with Gray Background</h3>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: that worked. also by just adding margin: auto 0; to the title also helped :) but your method will be better if i need a background same size as logo

Answer (score 0):

You can work with `@media` query for mobile user, like this.

```
@media (max-width < 568) {
 .box {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
   justify-content: center;
 }
}
```

**Explanation**:

You're telling the browse to display boxes in reverse orden on how you declare it.

so in this way you logo will be display down on the screen.

Have fun.